# MOSFET not switching solenoid lock

Tags: mosfet, solenoid

I'm trying to actuate a solenoid lock with the following specifications from the vendor's page:

- Working voltage: 12 Vdc
- Starting current: 0.9 A
- Steady current: 0.12 A

For this application, I'm using a circuit based on the answer to the question in this link: [MOSFET to run 12 V, 0.5 A door lock](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/234197/mosfet-to-run-12-v-0-5-a-door-lock)
My circuit diagram is as follows, with the solenoid wires connected to the J2 borne connector:
[image]

However, the IRLML2502 MOSFET is not able to actuate the solenoid lock when a logic pulse is supplied to its gate. The original idea is to operate it using 3.3V, but I also tested it using 5V to no success.

From what I understood, the datasheet gives a maximum of [image: R_{ds(on)} = \Omega] for [image: V_{GS} = 2.5 V], resulting in a voltage drop of 0.08 at 1 A.

Using a DMM, I measured the solenoid's current draw from activating the MOSFET gate using 5V logic on a protoboard. As soon as the 5V pin switches, the DMM shows the current of 9.9 mA, then goes out of the 200 mA range and settles at 182.1 mA for the rest of the pulse. The solenoid does not fully actuate in this setup, only when supplied 12.1 V (measured) directly from a 2.5 A DC power supply.

I'm suspecting here of the MOSFET not being able to handle the higher starting current. Am I missing any information here? What parameters should I consider in this case? Is it possible to use IRLML2502 MOSFET for this application? If not possible, any substitute parts reccomendations are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see why it would not work, but I don't see where the 5V or 3.3V signal comes from. Did you measure Gate voltage and Drain voltage? What happens if you short-circuit Drain to Source? Can you post a photo of the wiring setup, lock datasheet, and where does the 12V come from?

Comment: A simple troubleshooting thing is to directly short the drain and source pins at the MOSFET with a wire. Does the lock activate? If not, then the MOSFET has no chance. But if it it does, then the MOSFET must not be switching on properly.

Comment: Also, when the gate is high, measure Vds. It should be very low. If not, the MOSFET is not switching. If it is low, then the problem is likely elsewhere.

Comment: How long is your pulse to the gate?  Is it long enough for the lock to overcome its inertia and physically move?

Comment: What is the solenoid resistance?

Comment: @Justme I tried shorting Source and Drain and it actually worked. What is the logic here? Isn't this equivalent to just supplying the 12V directly? The 5V pulse of 10s duration comes form an Arduino Uno connected to the gate of the Mosfet, the 12V comes from a wall adapter. The lock datasheet is unfortunately in chinese...

Comment: Are you sure the Arduino pin is really an output and it really outputs 5V?

Comment: @mkeith Sorting source and drain worked. That means the Mosfet is capable of switching it then? Thus, the problem is either mechanical or on the microcontroller.

Comment: @JohnBirckhead My DMM is not able to measure it unfortunately. But since it draws ~180 mA, I would assume it's around 66 Ohm.

Comment: @Aaron I'm giving it 5 to 10 seconds pulses.

Comment: @Justme Yes, just measured it at 4.56 V. Maybe the pin current sourcing defective? I'll get another microcontroller to test it.

Comment: 4,56V output is suspiciously low if MCU supply is 5V. Are you absolutely sure you have the connections right? Post a photo.

Comment: No, opposite. That means that the MOSFET must not be turning on completely. Can you measure the voltage from source to drain when the MOSFET is on (or when you think it is on)?

Comment: Hi everyone, after applying the recommendations on the answer bellow and getting a different microcontroller that output closer to 5V, the solenoid starterd actuating. It was probably a combination of faulty both my components and mechanical defects. Anyhow, thanks for the MOSFET debuging tips, they were very useful!

Answer (score 2):

One thing that jumps out at me, there's a chance your door lock is either rusty, or isn't broken in. Put some 3 in 1 or low viscosity synthetic lubricant on it and then actuate it by hand a couple times.

Once the lock is moving freely by hand. Then feel your solenoid actuate. Is the power of the solenoid enough to match the force required to engage the door lock?

If yes. Make sure your the lock bolt is able to freely traverse and doesn't hit the jamb plate on your door.

If no... It may work if you pulse the solenoid repeatedly.

Lastly, solenoids in most applications actuate with the same force regardless of polarity. However, some have "favorite" directions. If it has a ferrous casing, mount, return spring, etc. it may slightly change the excursion profile.

Comment: I'll do what you recommended and try it again, thanks.

Comment: After lubricating the solenoid and using the repeated pulsing technique, it started working with a new IRLML2502 MOSFET on a different microcontroller. Thanks for the tips! It might have been a combination of the solenoid not being broken in and faulty parts...